# What is the Rails3 version of errors.add_to_base?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to write a custom validation in Rails 3, but following [this example](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/33-how-to-write-custom-validation-in-ruby-on-rails) I get:

```
'ActiveModel::DeprecatedErrorMethods.add_to_base' call is deprecated in Rails 3.0
```

What is the rails3 version of:

```
def validate
   errors.add_to_base "If you are attaching a file you must enter a label for it" if !attachment.blank? and attachment_label.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This should work in rails 3.1.3:

```
errors.add :base, "message"
```

Answer (score 38):

From http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base:

> Use `model_instance.errors[:base] << "Msg"` instead of deprecated `model_instance.errors.add_to_base("Msg")` for Rails 3.

Comment: If you want Rails to look up the message from a locale, you can use errors.add(:base, :your_error_symbol) and store it in [locale].activerecord.errors.[model].your_error_symbol

Answer (score 3):

For me this "hack" worked best:

```
instance.errors.add("", "Msg")
```

When I tried to specify `"base"` as the first argument, the word base kept getting inserted into my validation messages.

Comment: That's because you used the string `"base"` not the symbol `:base`. There is a difference: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

Comment: not the case, it adds `base` even as a symbol, at least for Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: I just checked this in my current project (rails 3.1.2), and base was not getting inserted into my messages.  Possible this changed in 3.1.3, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: I had the same problem but my issue was with rendering the error messages. Using `full_messages` instead of `messages` would remove "Base" from the message just fine.

Comment: @BrianDonovan the link no longer works. For anyone else, please see [the archived snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20140211012053/http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in below format,

errors[:base] << "Your Message"

It wont insert anything before your validation messages.