# Rails, custom validation and error not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, formtastic

I've currently five boolean attributes. I do a custom validation on them :

```
def limit_impacts
    i = 0
    choices = [self.first_attr, self.sec_attr, self.third_attr, self.fourth_attr, self.fifth_attr]
    choices.each do |choice|
      if choice == true
        i+=1
      end
    end
    if i > 2
      errors[:base] << ("There must be one or two impacts.")
    end
  end
```

The idea is to test if more than two of them are set to true, if it's the case, set an error.
I'm setting a `:base error` because it's not related directly to only one attribute.

I'm simply doing this for my validation : `validate               :limit_impacts`

and the part of the view handling this :

```
  = f.input :first_attr, :as => :boolean

  = f.input :sec_attr, :as => :boolean

  = f.input :third_attr, :as => :boolean

  = f.input :fouth_attr, :as => :boolean

  = f.input :fifth_attr, :as => :boolean
```

The problem is, when I check more than 2 checkboxes the entrie is not saving and that's normal, but no error message is showing up in the view.

What am I doing wrong ?

By the way I tested it in rails console :

```
MyModel.errors[:base]
 => ["There must be one or two impacts."]
```

And this syntax doesn't work either :

```
errors.add :base, "message"
```

EDIT : Here's my controller. It's about the edit method.

```
  def edit
    @page_title = t('projects.edit.title')
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @steps = @project.steps
    @rewards = @project.rewards
    @project_bearer = @project.user
  end
```

Nothing linked with these attributes.

When I try to create a project via the rails console, it returns me false  :

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > t = Project.create(:social_influence => true, :environmental_influence => true, :economical_influence => true)
=> <Project all my attributes ..>
2.0.0p247 :002 > t.save
(1.2ms)  BEGIN
(2.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

**SOLUTION :**

The problem was my update method, bewteen render and redirect. Thanks to @delba I solved it.
If you want to see the solution, there's a discussion in the comments of his answer.

Comment: The method `errors.add` works for a particular attribute, not for `:base`.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752106/what-is-the-rails3-version-of-errors-add-to-base

Comment: You need to use it this way: `model_instance.errors.add(:attribute_name, "error message, like 'cant be blank'")`

Comment: Yes you are right. But I checked the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3d0c0c6c95f8ed35c3fea79cfe93ec6e74f726ec/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L291) and the method `errors.add` normalize the message for `model.errors.full_messages` (before calling `errors[:attribute] << 'message'`) which is not necessary when we add a message directly to `:base`. For instance, `errors.add :first_name, 'is wrong'` will generate `First name is wrong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view containing the form, make sure you display the errors:

```
<%= form_for @my_model do |f|
  <% if @my_model.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="errors">
      <% @my_model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <%# the rest of the form %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
def create
  @my_model = MyModel.new(my_model_params)
  if @my_model.save
    redirect_to 'blabla'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

In your model:

```
validate :limit_impacts

private

def limit_impacts
  if [first_attr, sec_attr, third_attr, fourth_attr, fifth_attr].count(true) > 2
    errors[:base] << "There must be one or two impacts."
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the type of your first_attr..fifth_attr columns? Could you post the logs of an instance not saving please?

Comment: All of them are checkboxes, and the attributes are boolean. How can I post the logs of an instance not saving ?

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with your controller. Launch the rails server and in your Web Browser create an instance of `my_model` with more than 2 `impacts`. Then post the logs (what is written on your terminal). Thanks

Comment: I'm using foreman with Unicorn, do you still want the logs ? I can show you the controller instead if you want.

Comment: Yes please. If the requests aren't logged anywhere, show me the controller + routes. Anything really. Thanks

Comment: And check in your terminal if everything goes well: `m = MyModel.create(first_attr: true, second_attr: true, third_attr: true); m.errors.inspect` Post the result please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37231/discussion-between-user2462805-and-delba)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your validation method:

```
def limit_impacts
  choices = [first_attr, sec_attr, third_attr, fourth_attr, fifth_attr]
  errors[:base] << "There must be one or two impacts." if choices.count(true) > 2
end
```

Much cleaner, isn't it? :)

Could you show us your layout / your view bit which displays errors? I will update answer then.

Comment: Yeah a lot more cleaner, thanks for that.
My view is separated into partial but I'll try to mix them in order to show you more of it.

Comment: I read again your last sentence, I misunderstood it.Currently I'm not handling errors myself, Rails do it for me when other fields do not respect validations. I only have one custom validation.